# Wordpress .htaccess Modification

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site with this structure:

Home
About Us
Products
Product
Services
Contact

If I open
mysite.com/products
reads page-products.php
and

mysite.com/product
reads page-product.php

I need to use page-product.php as a generic page.
For Example...
mysite.com/product/The-Best-Product/32
read page-product.php?name=The-Best-Product&id=32)

And how about

mysite.com/john/
and reads page-user.php?username=john

Its possible to make something like that works?
Thanks!

Comment: @Paul you answered this question perfectly.

Comment: What is your `page-product.php`? A file in your WordPress template or is it independent from WP?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Apache Web server's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which is a very powerful tool to do just what you need. This would only help you if you are using Apache. Also, if you are not the Webmaster, mod_rewrite must have been enabled for use in .htaccess files.

The bottom of the page I linked has some examples on how to use this. Also, there are many tutorials around.